# Wrong Coloramp function in ArcGIS 10.2.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, hillshade

I want make elevation map use new method [Learn a new method](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0312/learn-a-new-method-for-displaying-hillshades-and-elevation-tints.html)
[image]

But i have problem with *Coloramp function* whatever the choice of color ramps.
[image]
What's wrong?

Comment: looks like it would stop at 255 m. Could it be a 8bit vs 16bit problem ?

Comment: It's 250m. 16 bit signed

Comment: The instruction say "you must make sure that the data is defined as 16-bit unsigned."

Comment: I try to 16 bit unsigned and didin't worked...

Answer (score 1):

In the Mosiac Dataset properties you could simply just create a Shaded Relief Function and assign a color ramp or colorcode [as described here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t000000p4000000)

[image]

Comment: This method simple but relief not beautiful